# I want to make a navigation bar that i can hide and unhide with javascript

Tags: javascript, nav

I want to make a navigation bar that i can hide and unhide with javascript. I know this should work from jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3pu868em/). Any help would be great thanks. I know it's something basic i've done wrong. Thanks for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hide the Navigation</title>
<style>
.hidding{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
   <ul>
       <a href="#"></a><li>Home</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>Contents</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>Social Media</li></a>
   </ul>
   <div class="handle">Menu</div>
</nav>
<script>
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul').toggleClass('hidding');               
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery but haven't included it on the page. Put this in the `<head>` section of the page to include it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, instead of toggling a class you can just use jQuery's [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
<script>
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul').toggle();             
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've put in your code but it still doesn't work for me when i test it in a browser. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Dodo... just add `http:` before `//`

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan. `//` would work in a regular HTTP web environment, but when viewing a file locally it won't work because it's trying to use the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Perfect!, thanks a million, that's done the trick! it's 05:56 but was totally worth it to get this working :D

Comment: @Dodo also, instead of `.toggle()` try also to play with `slideToggle()` makes a better *User-Experience*.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include jQuery before the script.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('hidding');               
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery to your page.

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

use `toggle/slideToggle` method:

`$('nav ul').toggle();` or `$('nav ul').slideToggle()`  instead of  `$('nav ul').toggleClass('hidding');`